# Codeigniter failing to connect to DB

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, database-connection, codeigniter-3

Alright so for some reason no matter what I do CI is refusing to connect to database. I've tried using another DB and so on and nothing happens

This is what I've ended up using as alternative way to connect to DB since default wont work either.

```
class ContentLoader extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database(); 
    }

    public function foo() {
        $res = $this->load->database();

        if($res == false) {
            echo "conn_failed";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my config

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'first_igniter',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: check these fields `'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'first_igniter',`

Comment: I did, I've tried changing them to invalid ones and I've gotten access denied which was correct but whenever I am using the correct ones it simply wont connect. I've used some method to display SQL erorr but it just returned 0

Answer (score 0):

Double check

1. username
2. password
3. database Name

---

and in `config/autoload.php` load database as well

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

---

and try simple select methods instead of your  code. 
Use [`$this->db->select();`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) it will show the rest of error

Comment: I got it on autoload and whenever I tried select nothing actually happened

Comment: I've got error_reporting(E_ALL); inside my index.php

Comment: Just to add up, I've added tried with select and the return was 0

Comment: in `index.php` set as `development` on here `define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'development');`

Comment: this from where??